# C# CryptoStream read/write in same file, filesizes are different

Tags: c#, encryption

im testing two simple functions, which are encrypt/decrypt the filevalue into the same file.

My first problem is that after encrypting, the filesize is different to the original file. By AES, output should be as same size as input, isnt it?

Here are my two simple functions. Please remember my Testparameters: a Textfile with simple Text as a input file, is exactly 128 Bytes in size and yes i know the problem about the IV - just for testing.

My output file is exactly 128+16 Bytes in size, but why? Looks like the IV behind the crypted value, but tests are negative. But: if i encrypt the textvalue and quit the debugger DIRECTLY AFTER cs.write(...), i get the correct size. I guess that the end of using(CryptoStream...) concats some stuff from the pipe to the encrypted file.

And second problem: i can not decrypt it: Although, buffer is 128 Bytes in size, the readerpos-Cursor is at 144 Bytes. It seems so, that my encrypted value is at it is: larger than the original.

```
      public static void EncryptFileB(string strInputFilename, string strPassword)
      {
            RijndaelManaged aesCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
            int buffersize = 128;

            using (FileStream fsInOut = new FileStream(strInputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsInOut, aesCrypto.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    // Prepare crypto
                    aesCrypto.KeySize = 256;
                    aesCrypto.BlockSize = 128;
                    aesCrypto.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPassword);
                    aesCrypto.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPassword);
                    aesCrypto.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    aesCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    // Prepare pointervars and buffer
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                    long readpos = 0;
                    long tmppos = 0;

                    // so long bytes in stream
                    while ((readpos = fsInOut.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)            // so long data in pipe
                    {
                        // remeber position
                        tmppos = fsInOut.Position;                          // remember Pos
                        fsInOut.Position = fsInOut.Position - readpos;      // set pointer back
                        cs.Write(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt16(readpos));      // write encrypted buffer in read stream
                        fsInOut.Position = tmppos;                          // reset pointer for correct read pos
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void DecryptFileB(string strInputFilename, string strPassword)
        {
            RijndaelManaged aesCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
            int buffersize = 128;

            using (FileStream fsInOut = new FileStream(strInputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsInOut, aesCrypto.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    // prepare crypto
                    aesCrypto.KeySize = 256;
                    aesCrypto.BlockSize = 128;
                    aesCrypto.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPassword);
                    aesCrypto.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPassword);
                    aesCrypto.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    aesCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    // prepare pos variables and buffer
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                    long readpos = 0;
                    long tmppos = 0;
                    
                    // so long bytes in crypto stream
                    while ((readpos = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        tmppos = fsInOut.Position;                               // remember pos   
                        fsInOut.Position = fsInOut.Position - readpos;           // set write position
                        fsInOut.Write(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt16(readpos));      // write encrypted buffer in read stream
                        fsInOut.Position = tmppos;                               // reset pos for new reading
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using the same stream for both reading and writing in this way seem really fragile to me. I would not make any assumptions about the amount of data the crypto stream writes, for all I know it might not do any writes until it is flushed/disposed.

Comment: You're using CBC mode and PKCS7 padding. The length of the ciphertext should normally be the length *l* of the plaintext plus the length *s* of the padding (1 <= *s* <= 16 bytes) plus the length of the IV (16 bytes). So ciphertext length would be between *l* + 17 and *l* + 32. If you add a MAC (and you should consider adding one), it will be a little longer still.

Comment: Actually, the code can't work because you set your key and IV after creating the encryptor and decryptor. Instead of your values, the initial values generated when the `RijndaelManaged` instance is created are used, so a different ciphertext should result each time. Use the MS examples as guide, e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged?view=net-7.0).

Comment: @Topaco, yes. Thanks. Through all my testing sessions, i loose the sight to it.

Comment: I am quite sure that the additional 16 Bytes coming with closing the cs-stream - at this moment. Now i got the decrypting-method running for testing with a text, which is a multitude to 128. But after decryption, the 16 Bytes are still at the end of the decrypted file. If i delete it after encryption, i will get a exeption - to less signs or similar - at decryption method....  hm. tomorrow, i will go ahead.

Comment: After more hours reworking and testing the code above: i am nearly sure, it depends on the size of the file. If the filesize is near the size of the buffersize, it does possibly not work. e.g. i resized the buffer to 1024 and tried with filesizes of 1024 bytes to 1040 bytes: just in this view steps: at a filesize of 1040: it worked and at 1038 i missed two bytes after decrypting... now i am writing a toolset, which creates many testfiles with sizes of 1 to n bytes. I then try to find out, which filesizes are not working.

Comment: After further tests and changes at my code: i wrote a tool which gave me 13T files, from size 1 byte to 13000 byte. Then, I encrypted and decrypted these files and checked they up with sha256. result: files, with a size of the buffer (e.g. 128 or 1024, depends on byte buffer[]) and the multitudes of the files (e.g. 256, 372 or 2048, 3072, 4096) and the following 15 sizes (e.g. 129, 130 up to 134 or 1025, 1026, 1027 up to 1041)) are not correctly decrypted. all other files are same after decryption. I want go in it with some more tries...